# When do you need a free hand for casting Shield?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

Is the verbal and somatic component executed when the spell is originally cast or do they take place when the reaction takes place?

For example, the fighter/sorcerer wants to use his bonus action with an off-hand weapon during the round the shield spell is triggered, does the somatic component of the triggered shield spell impact that option since a somatic component requires a free hand?

Answer (score 15):

The *Shield* spell is cast as a reaction. There is no "original" cast. And yes, in order to cast it, you must have a hand free. So if your hands are full (for example, because you're dual-wielding), you won't be able to cast it. If you think that you'll need to cast it, you could use your free object interaction to sheath one of your weapons at the end of your turn.

Comment: Understood, so that means if the fighter/sorcerer has initiative and used both his action and bonus action as a dual wielder, he would lose his ability to react with a shield spell if the opponent were to strike on their turn?

Comment: @Goblin Yep, unless the DM allowed him to drop one of his weapons as part of the reaction used to cast Shield.

Comment: If you are going dual wielding with a spellcaster, take the war caster feat, @Goblin